# Introducing secret variables to dockerfile on Github Actions

Tags: github, dockerfile

I am trying to configure my etc/pip.conf file to download a private PyPi artifactory while using a secret variable on my dockerfile.

## Dockerfile

```
FROM python
WORKDIR ./app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r pre-requirements.txt
RUN echo ${{ secrets.PIP }} > etc/pip.conf
RUN pip install -r post-requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "./simpleflask.py"]
```

## docker-image.yml

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Setup JFrog CLI
        uses: jfrog/setup-jfrog-cli@v2
        env:
          JF_ARTIFACTORY_SERVER: ${{ secrets.JFROG_CLI }}
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Build
        run: |
          docker build -t simple-flask .
          docker tag simple-flask awakzdev.jfrog.io/docker-local/simple-flask:latest
          docker push awakzdev.jfrog.io/docker-local/simple-flask:latest
```

pretty simple and straightfoward but my pipeline returns the following

```
Step 6/8 : RUN echo ${{ secrets.PIP }} > etc/pip.conf
 ---> Running in deb3e3f4167f
/bin/sh: 1: Bad substitution
The command '/bin/sh -c echo ${{ secrets.PIP }} > etc/pip.conf' returned a non-zero code: 2
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

#### Edit :

Trying a slightly difference approach and went to install dependencies in the pipeline

*my .yml looks like this now*

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Setup JFrog CLI
        uses: jfrog/setup-jfrog-cli@v2
        env:
          JF_ARTIFACTORY_SERVER: ${{ secrets.JFROG_CLI }}
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: install dependencies
        run: |
          pip config -v list
          echo "${{ secrets.PIP }}" > /etc/pip.conf
          pip install ganesha-experimental==2.0.1

      - name: Build
        run: |
          docker build -t simple-flask .
          docker tag simple-flask awakzdev.jfrog.io/docker-local/simple-flask:latest
          docker push awakzdev.jfrog.io/docker-local/simple-flask:latest
```

but the following error is being returned:

```
1s
Run pip config -v list
For variant 'global', will try loading '/etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'global', will try loading '/etc/pip.conf'
For variant 'user', will try loading '/home/runner/.pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'user', will try loading '/home/runner/.config/pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'site', will try loading '/usr/pip.conf'
/home/runner/work/_temp/09382b8f-ce09-4646-816f-fb337f40ad4b.sh: line 2: /etc/pip.conf: Permission denied
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: I need to get this to work any way possible.. is there a way to pip install and specifying the pip.conf location?

Comment: I've also tried creating a venv and it didnt pass.

Answer (score 0):

I've placed the secret on my .yml file instead.

as for the broken pip permissions I used

```
sudo chown runner /etc/
echo ${{ secrets.PIP }} > /etc/pip.conf
```

which resulted in another error with the contents of the pip.conf file (it was configured correctly through secrets)

so I found you can specify the url like so

```
ganesha_experimental==5.0.0 --find-links=https://awakzdev.jfrog.io/artifactory/
```